# How to list all ports and service with nftables?

Tags: services, port, nftables

It is simple to list all open ports and its services with firewll-cmd:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --list-all
```

How can get the list with nftables?

Comment: `nft list ruleset` lists all rules. grep the output for rules like `tcp dport.*accept`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's my `nftables` cheat sheet:

- Load rules: `nft -f /etc/sysconfig/nftables.conf` (this will append them to the existing ones, so flushing first might be required)
- Watch rules: `nft list ruleset`
- Reset rules: `nft flush ruleset`

Speaking of your request:

`nft list ruleset | grep dport`

Since tables and chains can be called pretty much anything, it's kinda hard to devise a script which will list only rules for `type filter hook input`.